# Python: fixed set of immutable items with attributes that refer to other items (complex Enum?)

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to solve a problem with a fixed set of named immutable items that have a number of attributes. The catch is that those attributes need to refer to other items.

My idea was to use enums with complex values, i.e. the items being enumerators, but the approach falls short. My current situation looks somewhat like this:

```py
class Item(enum.Enum):
    ITEM_A = dict(size=100, requirements=[])
    ITEM_B = dict(size=200, requirements=[(ITEM_A, 1)])

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __init__(self, values: dict):
        # ...
        self.__dict__.update(values)
```

One of the reasons to use an enum was that I want to use the items as keys in dictionaries, e.g. `available_items={Item.ITEM_A: 22, Item.ITEM_B: 45}`, and that works so far.

However, the cross-reference does not work at all:

- I would like to have a dict instead of a list of tuples in the `requirements`, but that won't work because inside the enum/class declaration, `ITEM_A` is a dict and *not* an Item
- I need to use the keys from the requirements to access entries of other dictionaries, e.g.

  ```
  for r_item, r_count in item.requirements:
      self.available[r_item] -= r_count
  ```

  This fails because r_item again is no Item, but a plain dict

I tried to explicitly use `Item.ITEM_A` in the requirements, but that fails since `Item` is not yet a defined name.

Any ideas on how to get out of this dilemma? I am aware that Enum may not be the appropriate solution but I didn't find alternatives that don't feel clumsy and awkward to use.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you are using enums, so I can't say "Yes, this is a good idea" -- but it did give me a chance to find and fix a bug, so thanks!

Comment: I am modeling part of a video game, the items need other items to be built. There's a fixed number of types of items, hence the enum. The naive implementation I came up with yesterday after posting this question is a dictionary of a simple Enum to item data, and I had to do the lookup everywhere in the code. 
I thought about making the ItemData class hashable and then creating a bunch of named globals, but that would also be only a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the functionality that you are looking for, you'll need to use the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library.  The just-released version of 3.1.5 has a bug-fix that supports this type of scenario, although a bit of fancy footwork is still required on your part.

The updated code:

```
from aenum import Enum, auto

class Item(Enum):
    ITEM_A = auto(size=100, requirements={})
    ITEM_B = auto(size=200, requirements={ITEM_A: 1})

    def __new__(cls, value, size, requirements):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        obj.size = size
        # fix requirements
        new_requirements = {}
        for k, v in requirements.items():
            if isinstance(k, auto):
                k = k.enum_member
            new_requirements[k] = v
        obj.requirements = new_requirements
        return obj
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I defaulted the requirements parameter to `None` now so I don't have to mention them everywhere and mashed the initialization into one line: `obj.requirements = dict([(k.enum_member, v) for k, v in requirements.items()]) if requirements else {}` Works like a charm!